# Allow EC2 Security Group access from Beanstalk Security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an **Amazon Beanstalk Load Balancer** setup which adds / removes ec2 servers as needed.  The security group for this load balancer is called `prod-sc`.

---

### [image]

I also have an **Amazon EC2** instance using security group `elasticsearch-sc`.

Now I need `elasticsearch-sc` to allow port **9200** to be accessed from `prod-sc`

However everytime I try to configure this in the `elasticsearch-sc` by providing the `prod-sc` Group ID, I get an error saying

`Could not update your security group rules (No changes were made): You may not define rules between a VPC group and a non-VPC group.`

---

### [image]

How can I give `prod-sc` access to `elasticsearch-sc`?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try creating `elasticsearch-sc` as a VPC security group?
Read the guide for more details.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-security-group.html

Comment: Ah Rohit! Thank you for pointing this out that you can create security groups with / without VPC, I thought this VPC configuration was done when creating the EC2 instance! So investigating what I found out is that actually my EC2 security group are in the VPC, but my beanstalks security groups are NOT. So should I create a new security group in VPC and re-assign my beanstalk instance to use it?

Comment: You can launch your beanstalk environment inside the same VPC and then your ec2 security group will be inside the VPC.
Read more here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo-vpc.html
Or you can create both your security groups outside the VPC.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you Rohit. One last thing, as I tried to duplicate my Beanstalk Security Group, I noticed it has an INBOUND PORT 80 for HTTP to source "amazon-elb/sg-4a2c346a (amazon-elb-sg)". What is this? I looked everywhere I can't find any reference to what this ID represents.

Comment: Beanstalk creates an EC2 instance for you and an ELB for you. Both have their own security group. Your EC2 instance is listening on port 80, we need to allow ELB to access the web server running on this EC2 instance. So the ELB security group "amazon-elb/sg-4a2c346a (amazon-elb-sg)" has been explicitly granted inbound access to port 80 on the EC2 instance.

Comment: Ok, it seems nothing is in my VPC, not even my RDS. Do I have to re-create beanstalk env, re-create rds, or is there a way to on the fly add them to the vpc?

Comment: Try recreating your environment in a vpc.